# How to call Fragment Activity so that it replace parent layout of mainActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a main activity in which i have navigation drawer and i want this main activity layout to work as parent layout:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.awesome.easypick.fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>
```

I want to replace this fragment part of layout with a FragmentActivity how can I do that? I cannot call the FragmentActivity normally like calling fragment. any idea how I can acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

A `FragmentActivity` is an `Activity`, not a `Fragment`.

[image: Fragment Activity Inheritance]

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

So compose your layout as your would for an `Activity`.